# Sql query , grouping result from left outer join to a single cell/field of main table

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-aggregation

Let's say that i have the following 3 tables :

```
   IDUser  Name    Surname

   1       Lucas   Wurth    
   2       John    Charson  
   3       Erik    Drown
```

---

```
 IDUser       IDLocation

   1            1  
   1            2  
   2            1  
   3            2
```

---

```
   IDLocation    Name

       1         Rome   
       2         Milan
```

a User Table , a Location table , and a table to assign a location to our users.
I'd like to extract from my database all the users and have a specific column where all assigned locations are reported like so:

```
   IDUser        Name    Surname    Locations

       1         Lucas   Wurth      Rome - Milan
       2         John    Charson    Rome
       3         Erik    Drown      Milan
```

**Note that the user 1 has both Rome & Milan assigned**

Currently my query:

```
SELECT 
U.IDUser,
U.Name,
U.Surname,
UL.Name AS LocationName
FROM Users U
LEFT OUTER JOIN UserLocation UL ON
UL.IDUser = U.IDUser
LEFT OUTER JOIN Location L ON
UL.IDLocation = L.IDLocation
```

Is obviously returning a total of 4 records instead of 3 , is it possible to achievie this using the aggregate function group by? and if so how should i do this?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: i'm using microsoft sql server management studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SqlServer you can use STRING_AGG :

```
SELECT 
      U.IDUser,
      U.Name,
      U.Surname,
      STRING_AGG(UL.Name, ' - ')  AS Locations
FROM Users U
LEFT OUTER JOIN UserLocation UL 
ON UL.IDUser = U.IDUser
LEFT OUTER JOIN Location L 
ON UL.IDLocation = L.IDLocation
GROUP BY U.IDUser, U.Name, U.Surname
```